# Damp slab in my living room

Tags: concrete, waterproofing

I live in FL and have a damp area on my slab in my living room in front of my front bay window which does not have a gutter.  As a result I have a musty smell in my house. I bought some UGL DRYLOK masonry waterproofer from Home Depot. Will this do the trick?

Answer (score 4):

Will the drylok work?  Maybe with minimal water.  What you need to do though is get gutters on your house or regrade your landscape.  Or both.  If water is draining under your slab there is nothing you can do to keep it from coming up through the floors.